Linux rights : Web app with User rights RWX creates files in folder, but it can not delete the files previously it created
I am new to linux, so sorry for maybe dumb question , but I am struggling with possibly basic user rights issue :
I have a Web App, which connects to filestore it runs from with some unknown user (can not find out which), but I have found a way to determine at least a group to it belongs to "tss".
Issue :
The group "tss" has RWX right to the folder, but when it creates any files inside that folder, group "tss" has always ONLY RW rights on all files created by itself. As I need to allow the web app to delete the old backups after some time, I need a X rights for the all files inside the folder the same app created previously (or in the future).
Question :
How do I change for the group "tss" rights for all FUTURE files inside the folder, tha same "tss" group will create? (I can not set rights on something, which was not yet created)
Screenshot attached.[enter image description here][1]
I tried "chmod g+s folder " to inherit permissions from folder, but seems it did not change anything  (new backup created has the same permissions )
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65br1ZeB.png

And are you sure that the app can write there? I mean, the app has a code for it.

Hi, Yes, sure, the app is using some account to write backup files into the folder. I can see new file created whenever I hit create backup, it does create new file, however always with read permissions set on the file itself, so no wonder it can not delete the files after 14days. Any ideas?
